# The namedwindow of opencv python has black layer in the centre

Tags: opencv

Iam using opencv python in linux mint.I tried to create a namedwindow  and added a track bar in it.But the track bar keeps showing at the bottom and at the centre there is black rectangle or black box and not sure on how to remove it.Iam using pycharm IDE and also ran the code in terminal but still produced the same output.

This is the picture i got as output and it has a black rectangular section in the centre.
[image]

Code:

```
import cv2

import numpy

def empty(a):
    pass

cv2.namedWindow("Track Bars",cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)

cv2.createTrackbar("Track1","Track Bars",100,200,empty)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: I think it does it to have something to display there (remember that opencv has a very asic gui, and trackbars are intended to be in an "image")... try using imshow with an image like:      `mat = np.zeros((15,400), dtype=np.uint8)`  at least in my pc it needs 15 in height  or it will put a weird width to the trackbar. This creates an almost invisible line and the trackbar

Comment: createTrackbar needs a window to be applied and you created it. But if you dont embed an image inside that window with imshow, it ll show nothing.

Comment: Thanks for helping out.I tried what you said and it worked.